# How to type text in front of a variable

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I will try to explain this the best way I can. I am making a domain checker and that works for me, now I have a function that shows some of the domains I have in my var named "domains" once I type in a DOT 'because all the variables domains begin with a dot' all the domains will appear but when I write some text before I put the DOT it will not appear anymore. What do I have to change to let it show the text before the DOT? Here is the code I use, and some picture how it looks right now.

```
<body>
<center>
<h2>Autocomplete domein</h2>

<p>Start typing:</p>

<form autocomplete="off" action="#">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Domain">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</center>
<script>
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

var domain = [".nl",".com",".net",".org",".network",".at",".co",".co.uk"
,".be",".bl",".us",".eu",".uk", ".lu"];

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), domain);
</script>

</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```html
<body>
<center>
<h2>Autocomplete domein</h2>

<p>Start typing:</p>

<form autocomplete="off" action="#">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Domain">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</center>
<script>
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      var name ='';
      if(this.value.indexOf('.')>=0){
        val =this.value.slice(this.value.indexOf('.'));
        name = this.value.slice(0,this.value.indexOf('.'));
      }
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          b.innerHTML = name;
          b.innerHTML += "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + name + arr[i] + "'>";
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

var domain = [".nl",".com",".net",".org",".network",".at",".co",".co.uk"
,".be",".bl",".us",".eu",".uk", ".lu"];

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), domain);
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: It doesn`t work. What it does for me is that without typing the DOT that it still shows the domain names. But I want to type in front of the domains so like: usa.com, usa.nl, usa.uk.Now it shows nothing or only the domain names if I begin typing with the domain names.

Comment: if you type "usa.com", i removed the `usa`, then the ".com" can match it

Comment: Thanks dude! 1 more thing! it Now shows all the domain names, even when I typed some text in front of it, only it doesn`t show the text+domain only the domain names, how can I make the text appear in front of the domains to?

Comment: @bruhbruh, can you give some exact examples? so i can know what you want

Comment: What you made now is this example: [ned.] .nl .com etc. But what I want is: [ned.] ned.nl ned.com etc. So the text I type for the domain does not appear only the domains will appear now, but I want also the text to be visible under each other if you know what I mean.